# Pandas Groupby with Multi-level column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to know how to transform a table and to get my desired outcome:

**My Sample Dataset:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    "ID":[111,111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333],
    "Section":["CS01","CS01","IT01","IT01","CS02","CS02","CS02","HS01","HS01"],
    "Subject":["Hist","Pol","Pol","Arts","Pol","Hist","Arts","Pol","Hist"],
    "Activity":["Quiz 1","Quiz 2","Quiz 3","Quiz 1","Quiz 2","Quiz 3","Quiz 1","Quiz 2","Quiz 3"],
    "Pass":[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
    })
```

**What it looks like:**

```
    ID      Section     Subject     Activity    Pass
0   111     CS01        Hist        Quiz 1      1
1   111     CS01        Pol         Quiz 2      0
2   111     IT01        Pol         Quiz 3      0
3   111     IT01        Arts        Quiz 1      1
4   222     CS02        Pol         Quiz 2      1
5   222     CS02        Hist        Quiz 3      1
6   222     CS02        Arts        Quiz 1      0
7   333     HS01        Pol         Quiz 2      1
8   333     HS01        Hist        Quiz 3      0
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

```
ID  Section Subject Quiz 1      Quiz 2      Quiz 3      
                    0   1   NA  0   1   NA  0   1   NA
111 CS01    Hist    0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
111 CS01    Pol     0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
111 IT01    Arts    0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
111 IT01    Pol     0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
222 CS02    Arts    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
222 CS02    Hist    0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
222 CS02    Pol     0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
333 HS01    Hist    0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
333 HS01    Pol     0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
```

What I want is to make the "Subject" column as level 2 and "Pass" column for its level 1 with "NA" column.

So far what I only have is this:

```
df.groupby(["ID","Section", "Subject","Activity"])["Pass"].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
```

But this doesn't have the "NA" column nor the "Activity" as Level 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create all possible combination in first step by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and then apply your solution with `MultiIndex` and `dropna=False` in value_counts:

```
s = df.set_index(["ID","Section", "Subject","Activity"])["Pass"] 
df = (s.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels))
       .groupby(level=[0,1,2,3])
       .value_counts(dropna=False)
       .unstack([3,4], fill_value=0)
       .sort_index(axis=1))
```

---

```
print (df)
Activity            Quiz 1         Quiz 2         Quiz 3        
Pass                   0.0 1.0 NaN    0.0 1.0 NaN    0.0 1.0 NaN
ID  Section Subject                                             
111 CS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   1   0      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      1   0   0      0   0   1
    CS02    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    HS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    IT01    Arts         0   1   0      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      1   0   0
222 CS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    CS02    Arts         1   0   0      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   1   0
            Pol          0   0   1      0   1   0      0   0   1
    HS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    IT01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
333 CS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    CS02    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    HS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      1   0   0
            Pol          0   0   1      0   1   0      0   0   1
    IT01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
```

EDIT: Solution working with duplicates:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    "ID":[111,111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333],
    "Section":["CS01","CS01","IT01","IT01","CS02","CS02","CS02","HS01","HS01"],
    "Subject":["Hist","Pol","Pol","Arts","Pol","Hist","Arts","Pol","Hist"],
    "Activity":["Quiz 1","Quiz 2","Quiz 3","Quiz 1","Quiz 2","Quiz 3","Quiz 1","Quiz 2","Quiz 3"],
    "Pass":[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
    })

df = pd.concat([df, df.head()])
print (df)
    ID Section Subject Activity  Pass
0  111    CS01    Hist   Quiz 1     1
1  111    CS01     Pol   Quiz 2     0
2  111    IT01     Pol   Quiz 3     0
3  111    IT01    Arts   Quiz 1     1
4  222    CS02     Pol   Quiz 2     1
5  222    CS02    Hist   Quiz 3     1
6  222    CS02    Arts   Quiz 1     0
7  333    HS01     Pol   Quiz 2     1
8  333    HS01    Hist   Quiz 3     0
0  111    CS01    Hist   Quiz 1     1 <- duplicates
1  111    CS01     Pol   Quiz 2     0 <- duplicates
2  111    IT01     Pol   Quiz 3     0 <- duplicates
3  111    IT01    Arts   Quiz 1     1 <- duplicates
4  222    CS02     Pol   Quiz 2     1 <- duplicates
```

First use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and reshape ony last level by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), add all possible combinations of `levels` by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and add column `NaN` filled by `1` if all values are `0` in both columns tested by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), last `unstack` for `MultiIndex` in columns, change order of levels and sort `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(["ID","Section", "Subject","Activity"])["Pass"]
         .value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0))

df1 = df1.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels), fill_value=0)
df1[np.nan] = df1.eq(0).all(axis=1).view('i1')
df1 = df1.unstack().swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df1)
Activity            Quiz 1         Quiz 2         Quiz 3        
Pass                   0.0 1.0 NaN    0.0 1.0 NaN    0.0 1.0 NaN
ID  Section Subject                                             
111 CS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   2   0      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      2   0   0      0   0   1
    CS02    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    HS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    IT01    Arts         0   2   0      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      2   0   0
222 CS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    CS02    Arts         1   0   0      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   1   0
            Pol          0   0   1      0   2   0      0   0   1
    HS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    IT01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
333 CS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    CS02    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
    HS01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      1   0   0
            Pol          0   0   1      0   1   0      0   0   1
    IT01    Arts         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Hist         0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
            Pol          0   0   1      0   0   1      0   0   1
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned a new technique from how you explain everything plus your code is pretty clean and straight forward

Comment: I'm getting "ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!", can you help me understand why I'm getting this on a different dataset?